# Find object pattern in array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient way to find a object pattern in an array.
Here is the problem that I have to tackle. I'm writing a tangible interface application that collects data from the webcam, converts it in to a black and white image from which I create an array. The array that is created looks similar to this:

```
1111111111111111111111111111
1111110001111111111000111111
1111100000111111110000011111
1111100000111111110000011111
1111110001111111111000111111
1111111111111111111111111111
```

Where the zeros represent the color black in the image. I have about 32 (4 rows with 8 circles in each) circles and I need to find an efficient way to find their coordinates. I don't need the whole shape, just a set of coordinates for each circle.

Thank you for the help.

Regards,
Teodor Stoyanov

Comment: What's the relation of circles and their coordinate and this array?

Comment: Intriguing to say the least. I'm interested in what the answers will be.

Comment: It looks a lot like homework. Please state it is or not.

Comment: @Henk: I agree, it seems like this is homework in an AI class. In fact, I remember doing something similar in my AI class I took in college, except we had to take it further than shape recognition. We had to help a remote control car drive along a track we built.

Comment: Based on the link in the comments farther down, it appears to be homework.  "http://home.aubg.bg/students/TVS070/binArray.txt" -- not that the link can be resolved.  There's no TVS070 folder and the two TVS folders in there are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Three options that I can see immediately (Tuple is used to represent the coordinates in your matrix):

1. You could use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) for
   each point in the matrix, the bit is set if the coordinate has an O, cost would be
   O(row length x column length) for storage. Retrieval is O(1) if you know the coordinates you want to check otherwise, O(n) if you just want to find all O's
2. You could use a `List<Tuple<int,int>>`
   to only store the coordinates for
   each O in the matrix, cost would be
   O(m) for storage, m being the number of O's. Retrieval is also O(m)
3. Alternatively to option 2 you could
   use a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>,
   bool>`, which allows O(1) retrieval
   time if you know the coordinates you
   want to check.

Comment: Did you understand what is the problem? I can't understand it.

Comment: there is also the `BitVector32` with 'assignable' `Slots`. Each slot can be easily assigned as VBytes["A"], VBytes["B"], etc., IIRC. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeb3ez18.aspx

Comment: That's what I'm using, a bitaray and a list to store the coordinates. The thing is that I want to find only one set of coordinates for each object, but an object consists of several tangent 0s in both dimensions. So If I have the coordinates for the object the next coordinates should be for the next circle, not for the next 0 in my current circle.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an arbitrary 0 and do a flood fill from it.  Average the coordinates of all the 0s you find to get the center of the circle.  Erase the 0s you flooded and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't an easy way to do this, but the best thing you can do is tinker around with [Artificial Neural Networks](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArtificial_neural_network&ei=clrxTIWjIIWvngftjZW4Cg&usg=AFQjCNGCnD4bgXrh2AS9UWwPKM2uXg_bKg&sig2=2ON9rkzgGg8fR06N0qDkZw). They allow you to feed in data and get an output over many different data inputs. If you build the network right, it'll self-adjust its weights over many iterations.

Sorry, but I doubt you're going to get the exact solution spelled out for you in code. Although I haven't used any of these libraries or resources, a quick glance over them makes them look pretty decent:

- http://franck.fleurey.free.fr/NeuralNetwork/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/